# ActiveAdmin role for mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, mass-assignment

In my models I have defined different roles for mass assignment. Some fields are `attr_accessible :as => :default`. Other fields are `attr_accessible :as => [:default, :admin]`.

How can I allow ActiveAdmin to be able to update attributes as an admin role?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the with_role options for ActiveAdmin controllers. For example:

```
# app/admin/users.rb
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  controller { with_role :admin }
end
```

Comment: +1, but it's better to put it into an initializer (`config/initializers/active_admin.rb`)

Comment: @KARASZIIstván could you elaborate on your comment?  I've got it working at the /admin/(model) level, but cannot get it working in the initializer.  Thanks!

Comment: @DaveCollins I posted it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Venkat said in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13072234/221213) you can do that with the `with_role` option. But it's a better idea IMHO to insert it in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` instead of in every controller:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  ResourceController.class_eval do
    with_role :admin
  end
end
```